# How to make a boxplot in ggplot where median lines change colour depending on the group?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working with data that has about 30 different groups and some of the fill colors that represent these groups in the boxplots are very dark. I would like the median line of the boxplots to vary between black and white depending on if the fill colour is light or dark (I have this indicated as a variable of two levels in my data frame). Here is a small example:

```
library(ggplot2)
test <- cbind.data.frame(value = rnorm(200), group = factor(rep(1:4, 50)), medcol = rep(c("light", "dark", "light", "dark"), 50))

ggplot(data = test, aes(x = group, y = value, fill = group)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('1' = "black", '2' = "white", '3' = "darkred", '4' = "lightblue"))
```

[image: example]

The goal in this example would be to make the median lines of group 1 and 3 white while keeping the black in groups 2 and 4. I'm a bit confused on how to do this since usually in `ggplot` we indicate aesthetics individually by observation or data frame row, but here its like trying to indicate it by group since the median of each group is a single value. Adding something like `stat_summary(fun = median, geom = "line", aes(colour = medcol))` was the ide I had, but it doesn't work and raises a warning:

```
geom_path: Each group consists of only one
observation. Do you need to adjust the
group aesthetic?
```

EDIT: forgot to mention I want to change the median line ONLY while keeping the outline of the boxplots black.

Comment: Would this work? You can use the col aesthetic for geom_boxplot 

ggplot(data = test, aes(x = group, y = value, fill = group)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(color = medcol), show.legend = FALSE) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("light" = "gray90", "dark" = "gray20")) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c('1' = "black", '2' = "white", '3' = "darkred", '4' = "lightblue"))

Comment: this would change the outline colour wouldnt it though? My bad I forgot to mention I don't want to change the outline colour. I want to change exlusively the median line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I had a moment of inspiration and came up with this:

```
ggplot(data = test, aes(x = group, y = value, fill = group, colour = medcol)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('1' = "black", '2' = "white", '3' = "darkred", '4' = "lightblue")) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c(light = "white", dark = "black")) + 
  geom_boxplot(color = "black", fill = NA, fatten = NULL)
```

[image: result]

This is simply doing what @Henry Cyranka suggested in a comment on the initial post but in order to give the effect that the outlinea of the boxplots are unchanged we overlay boxplots with the colour set to black and with no fill. The median line of the second `geom_boxplot` also needs to be removed. Here I do it by doing `fatten = NULL`. The only thing that bothers me now is that I get some warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: Removed 1 rows containing missing values
(geom_segment). 
2: Removed 1 rows containing missing values
(geom_segment). 
3: Removed 1 rows containing missing values
(geom_segment). 
4: Removed 1 rows containing missing values
(geom_segment).
```

Which I suspect are due to the `fatten = NULL` hack. They don't seem to have an effect on the actual plot but I'd rather deal with them if someone knows how to.

EDIT: using `fatten = 0` gets rid of the warnings

Answer (score 3):

This is a little bit of a hack (had to guess at the box width) but otherwise seems OK:

```r
theme_set(theme_bw())
wid <- 0.72
ggplot(data = test, aes(x = group, y = value, fill = group)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c('1' = "black", '2' = "white", '3' = "darkred", '4' = "lightblue")) +
    stat_summary(geom="segment",
                 fun.data= function(y) data.frame(y=median(y), yend=median(y)),
                 aes(x=as.numeric(group)-wid/2,xend=as.numeric(group)+wid/2,
                     colour=medcol),size=3) +
    scale_colour_manual(values=c('light' = gray(0.8), 'dark' = gray(0.2)))
```

[image: boxplot with light and dark median lines]